# Opening MacWrite documents

Tags: mac

I have some old documents that were created with MacWrite (I think it was MacWrite Pro). Is there any software that will run on a modern system that can read these files?

Alternately, is the file format documented somewhere so that I can write my own program to translate the files?

Answer (score 2):

MacWrite II (ver 1.1v3) runs in Sheepshaver ... I don't have MacWrite Pro in there, so that maybe means I tried it and it didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

An early version of AppleWorks is your best bet for something that has a chance to run on Leopard or Snow Leopard in the classic environment.

Some of the early mac source code is getting released by the [Computer History Museum](http://www.computerhistory.org/highlights/macpaint/) but I don't know of the file format being documented well enough to be of use to a programmer. It might be easier to locate someone with a working classic mac than to reverse engineer the file format.

Best of luck!